# How to add product specification table in long description field in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options

I am working on magento project which requires product specifications in table format and some of the fields on that table dynamically change values based on the selected attributes.
I tried making changes in `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog/product/view/description.phtml`

By adding blocks and widgets but they only show values in static format. I want the cells to show information in dynamic way.

I followed some blogs and they say it can be possible by using Ajax and JavaScript, but I don't understand how to use this to find selectors of those attributes. I already enabled debug hints from the admin panel but am still unable to find selectors responsible for those attributes.

https://www.malabargoldanddiamonds.com/malabar-settings/mine-solitaire-yellow-gold-ring-mount-r76119y.html

I saw a website doing the same thing, and it is also built on Magento 1.9. For this site, the values are changing in the below table as per the size of the ring selected and diamond quality selected..

Comment: They creat ajax request based on selection of options.

Comment: can you just provide me any resource so that I can do the same ??

Comment: This is the problem. I don't know what to select. I used debug option for the same but got no luck...

Answer (score 1):

optech is a best billing inventory software in coimbatore used by retail shop,gst billing software,inventory control, accounts and invoicing.Call 98422 90667 now for FREE Demo.
[enter link description here](https://www.optechsoft.com/index.html)